# Lost Heroku password, original email no longer exists to retrieve reset

Tags: heroku

I have lost my login password to my Heroku app. Also, the original email I signed up with no longer exists so I can't retrieve a reset email.

Can anyone suggest how I can get access to my account from the Heroku web site under these circumstances?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Heroku CLI is still working against the old email I would suggest setting up a new Heroku account with a new email address. Add your new account as a collaborator via `heroku sharing:add <newemail>` and then transfer the app to the new email using `heroku sharing:transfer <newemail>`.

When you've transferred all your apps to the new email use `heroku auth:logout` and then `heroku auth:login` and use your new credentials.